# carousel is not displaying in react

Tags: reactjs, carousel

M using a carousel with reactstrap react having seperate compoment as  carousel component but then this does not work 
  the error thrown is about the active index nothing is displayed due to the active index.

```
  const items=[
 {
 src:"https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg",
 altText:"1",
 caption:"s1"
 },
 {
 src:"https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg",
  altText:"2",
  caption:"s2"
  },
  {
src:"https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg",
altText:"3",
  caption:"s3"
  }
 ];

     export default class  DisplayCarousel extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={activeIndex:0};
    this.next=this.next.bind(this);
    this.previous=this.previous.bind(this);
    this.goToIndex=this.goToIndex.bind(this);
    this.onExiting=this.onExiting.bind(this);
    this.onExited=this.onExited.bind(this);
}
onExited()
{ 
    console.log("jjjjjjjjjjjj");
    this.animating=false;
}
 onExiting()
 { 
    this.animating=true;
    console.log("ddddddddddd");
  }
 goToIndex(newIndex)
  {  
    if(this.animating)return;
        this.setState({activeIndex:newIndex});
    console.log("ooooooo");
   }
   previous()
   {   
    if(this.animating)return;
    const nextIndex=this.state.activeIndex===0?items.length-1:this.state.activeIndex-1;
    this.setState({activeIndex:nextIndex});
    console.log("llllllll");
   }
   next()
    {  
    if(this.animating)return;
    const nextIndex=this.state.activeIndex===items.length-1?0:this.state.activeIndex+1;
    this.setState({activeIndex:nextIndex});
    console.log("ddddddd");
   }
   render(){
    const { activeIndex }=this.state;
    const slides=items.map((item)=>{
        return(
          <CarouselItem onExiting={this.onExiting} onExited={this.onExited} key={item.src}>
              <img src={item.src} alt={item.altText}/>
              <CarouselCaption captionText={item.caption} captionHeader={item.caption}/>
          </CarouselItem>
        );
    });
    return(
        <Carousel activeIndex={this.activeIndex} next={this.next} previous={this.previous}>
          <CarouselIndicators items={items} activeIndex={this.activeIndex} onClickHandler={this.goToIndex}  />
            {slides}
          <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="previousSlide" onClickHandler={this.previous}/>
          <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="nextSlide" onClickHandler={this.next}/> 
        </Carousel>
        )
   }
   }
```

errors thrown are as follows can anyone help me understand how come the value is undefined for activeindex i dont understand

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `activeIndex` is marked as required in `CarouselIndicators`, but its value is `undefined`.

  Line 75:  'activeIndex' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Change `activeIndex={this.activeIndex}` to `activeIndex={activeIndex}`

Comment: line 75 i have to changed now no error but carousel slides dont display

Comment: Yes. you need to change `<Carousel activeIndex={this.activeIndex} ..` to `<Carousel activeIndex={activeIndex}`

Comment: can you please explain me about the working as to why this was happening what "const { activeIndex }=this.state;"?

Comment: hows this.animatiing working too it has no state what is it exactly

Comment: `const { activeIndex }=this.state;` means `activeIndex = this.state.activeIndex` and you can use it as `activeIndex` in your jsx. while `this.activeIndex` mean property of class which was `undifined` in your case.

Comment: if i dont write const { activeIndex }=this.state; then i can use  this.state.activeIndex directly right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181073/discussion-between-juned-lanja-and-tested).